# How can I get keystroke events for an inactive window in Cocoa?

Tags: macos, cocoa, keyboard-events

I want to get a key press event say "space bar" to an application that is not active now or is minimized. How can that event be received by that application without making it active to front.

KeyDown and keyUp events can be received only to the active windows as per my knowledge. Could anyone please help me?

```
- (void) keyDown: (NSEvent *) event

    NSLog(@"KEY PRESSED == %d",[event keyCode]);
}
```

This is the code for the keyDown event I use. But this is not fired when the app is minimised.  I need to get this event in minimized state also.

Comment: @Raptor code entered what I have done so far.

Comment: How can an inactive window be "key", and therefore receive keystrokes?